# what is meaning of callback in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Returns the device's current position to the geolocationSuccess callback with a Position object as the parameter. If there is an error, the geolocationError callback is passed a PositionError object.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                         [geolocationError],
                                         [geolocationOptions]);
```

Answer (score 0):

geolocationSuccess is a function, that you have to define, to be triggered in the case that everything was ok, and error if something went wrong

Example:

```
geolocationSuccess: function () {
  alert ("OK to get geolocation!")
}

geolocationError: function () {
  alert ("Something went wrong on geolocation")
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                         geolocationError,
                                         [geolocationOptions]);
```